# program to solve cubic polynomials

Tags: python, solver, polynomials

I have this program from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic) to try to solve cubic polynomial formulas, by first converting to a depressed cubic polynomial formula and then making use of the trigonometric solution in the case we have three real roots, or finding the complex solution otherwise:

```
def solve_cubic(a,b,c,d):
    if a==0:
        raise Exception("Not a cubic function")
    p = (3*a*c-b**2)/3*a**2
    q = (2*(b**3)-9*a*b*c+27*(a**2)*d)/27*a**3
    roots = []

    D = q**2/4 + p**3/27

    if D<0:
        for k in range(3):
            t_k = 2*np.sqrt(-p/3)*np.cos( (1/3) * np.arccos(((3*q)/(2*p))*np.sqrt(-3/p)) -2*np.pi*k/3 ) 
            r_k = t_k - b/(3*a)
            roots.append(t_k)
    else:
        u1 = -q/2 + np.sqrt(D)
        u2 = -q/2 - np.sqrt(D)
        tmp1 = u1**(1/3) if u1>=0 else -1*(-u1)**(1/3)
        tmp2 = u2**(1/3) if u2>=0 else -1*(-u2)**(1/3)
        t1 = tmp1 + tmp2
        eta1 = (-1+np.sqrt(3)*1j)/2
        eta2 = (-1-np.sqrt(3)*1j)/2
        t2 = eta1*tmp1 + eta2*tmp2
        t3 = eta2*tmp1 + eta1*tmp2

        r1 = t1 - b/(3*a)
        r2 = t2 - b/(3*a)
        r3 = t3 - b/(3*a)
        
        roots.append(r1)
        roots.append(r2)
        roots.append(r3)

    return roots,D
```

Testing on the following values for my coefficients (from a real test case):

```
a: 0.0675657480231065
b: 0.00753445257071735
c: 0
d: -6.512869360794891e-10
```

So we are in the case where the discriminant is negative, and the t_k obtained value does makes the depressed polynomial equal to 0, but the r_k value root of the original polynomial doesn't nullify it and i struggle to find where i messed up the formulas.

Comment: You're missing parentheses around your divisors when computing `p` and `q`, and after the trigonometric computation you're returning the roots of the depressed cubic instead of the original cubic. There may be bugs in the complex solver but I find it tricky to follow your implementation.